# averaging over subsets of array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of the shape (10, 10, 10, 60). The dimensions could be arbitrary but this just an example.

I want to reduce this to an array of `(10, 10, 10, 20)` by taking the mean over some subsets I have two scenarios:

**1**: Take the mean of every `(10, 10, 10, 20)` block i.e. have three `(10, 10, 10, 20)` block and take the mean between the three. This can be done with: `m = np.mean((x[..., :20], x[..., 20:40], x[...,40:60]), axis=3)`. My question is how can I generate this when the last dimension is arbitrary without writing some explicit loop? So, I can do something like:

```
x = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10, 60)
result = np.zeros((10, 10, 10, 20))
offset = 20
loops = x.shape[3] // offset
for i in range(loops):
    index = i * offset
    result += x[..., index:index+offset]
result = result / loops
```

However, this does not seem too pythonic and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

**2**: Another scenario is that I want to break it down into 10 arrays of the shape `(10, 10, 10, 2, 3)` and then take the mean along the 5th dimension between these ten arrays and then reshape this to `(10, 10, 10, 20)` array as original planned. I can reshape the array and then again take the average as done previously and reshape again but that second part seems quite inelegant.

Comment: For part2 : Could you elaborate on the breaking down part? Or give us a working loopy implementation?

Comment: Actually your solution would work for both the parts, it seems! I just need to reshape differently, I think. Let me try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape splitting the last axis into two, such that the first one has the length as the number of blocks needed and then get the average/mean along the second last axis -

```
m,n,r = x.shape[:3]
out = x.reshape(m,n,r,3,-1).mean(axis=-2) # 3 is no. of blocks
```

Alternatively, we could introduce [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for noticeable performance boost -

```
In [200]: x = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10, 60)

In [201]: %timeit x.reshape(m,n,r,3,-1).mean(axis=-2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 430 µs per loop

In [202]: %timeit np.einsum('ijklm->ijkm',x.reshape(m,n,r,3,-1))/3.0
1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop
```